# Return C++ integer array in Python ctypes / numpy ctypeslib incorrect output

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I am attempting to create a C++ function that will return a pointer to an array, which I can then use in numpy. I seem to be stuck at the very basics. When I print out the values of the array I get back, (which in this case should just be the numbers 0 to 99), after 83 I don't get expected results. When I ask my c++ function to print out the contents of the array everything seems fine. Does anybody know what is going on here?

**edit:**

So I cannot return a variable that has gone out of scope. I understand that. So how can I return an array back to python, without passing in a pointer to one in the arguments?

My Python file:

**python_file.py**

```
import ctypes
import itertools
import numpy as np

h_list=np.array(range(100), dtype=int)
length = len(h_list)
data = h_list.astype(np.int32)
lib = ctypes.CDLL('/Path/to/file/ctypes_test/hello.so')
mynum = lib.mynum
mynum.restype = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, shape=(length,), flags='C_CONTIGUOUS') 
mynum.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ctypes.c_int, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),
                  ctypes.c_int]
h = mynum(data, length)
for i in h:
    print i
```

The truncated output, as you can see after 83 things go funny:

**Output:**

```
...
...
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
-23162618
-671088158
250053520
1
261248736
1
246869272
1
0
0
250053520
1
1359648784
32767
246824912
1
```

My C++ file:

**hello.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
    int * mynum(int *hkls, int length){
    int out [length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        out[i]=hkls[i];
    }
    int * out_a = out;
    return out_a;
}
}
```

My makefile:

**makefile**

```
main: hello.cpp
    g++-6 -shared -O3 -Wl,-install_name,hello.so -o hello.so -fPIC hello.cpp
```

Comment: In `mynum()` address to a local variable is returned, it should not be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope